# Контакт на сокетах или?

Tags: android, вконтакте, сокеты

Скажите приложение для андроида Вконтакте на сокетах или раз в пару секунд отправляет серверу запрос на наличие сообщений-новостей и т д???

Comment: "Отправка раз в пару секунд запроса" - это также сокеты (можно конечно через обратный пуш, но так не делают - нет смысла).

Так что ответ - да,  на сокетах.

 (хотя я думаю, подразумевалось постоянное подключения vs запросы).

Comment: спасибо, значит приложение выполняет роль браузера

Comment: с какой стороны посмотреть. некоторые приложения для андроида (да и для айоси)  - это просто браузер, который отображает сайт.

То приложения для вконтакта, которое я видел (оффициальное) - не является браузером. Хотя для конечного пользователя оно может удачно прикидываться браузером.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего используется так называемая технология «long polling»:
https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll

Если вкратце, принцип действия следующий: клиент делает long-poll запрос, а сервер удерживает его, пока не произойдёт какое-нибудь событие (новое сообщение, новость и т.д.) или не произойдёт таймаут (25-30 секунд). Происходит событие — сервер присылает JSON. Клиенту остаётся обрабатывать JSON-объекты, соответствующие событиям, а также переустанавливать соединение в случае таймаута.

По ссылке также можно прочитать, что используются идентификаторы событий, с помощью которых клиент гарантированно не пропустит событие, даже если оно произойдёт в промежутке между установлением соединений :)